# One Year Limited Warranty

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty

Is the one year limited warranty provided by Apple with a MacBook Pro international?

If I buy the MacBook Pro from US and use it in India, will the limited warranty be applicable in India?

Answer (score 0):

I bought my MacBook Air in Hong Kong and I live in Ireland. The condition for the Warranty and AppleCare was that I had to pay for postage to Hong Kong where they would handle it.

Comment: Weren't they ready to fix it in Ireland itself?

Comment: @AnkitGohel I'm not sure if they could have, Ireland doesn't have many Apple Stores. But the thing was because I bought it in Hong Kong, the warranty was only good in Hong Kong.

Comment: Did you buy the extended two year AppleCare? Because AppleCare is supposed to be international I think.

Comment: @AnkitGohel Yes

Comment: "The AppleCare Protection Plan for Mac and iPod provide global repair coverage." - according to the official Apple site. Do they not do this?

Comment: @AnkitGohel Just telling you my experience